# What is "an engaging content program"?

Tags: meaning

What is "an engaging content program"? 
I am reading a text about email-marketing and this phrase puzzled me.
Here is some context:

It’s time to start working on a newsletter design that converts. Whether it’s for a corporation or your personal brand, email has the power to:
   - Connect you with a large audience frequently and consistently
   - Keep the costs of sharing new information low by cultivating a channel of your own
   - Allow you to scale an engaging content program quickly
   - Share compelling calls to action to steer your audience in a specific direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, I'd take the words to follow the following definitions:

> **Engaging** *adjective*
> Charming and attractive: *an engaging smile*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/engaging)
>
> **Content (2)** *noun*
> 1.4 Information made available by a website or other electronic medium: [as modifier]: *online content providers*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/content#nav2)
>
> **Program(me)** *noun*
> 1 A planned series of future events or performances: *a weekly programme of films*; *the programme includes Dvořák’s New World symphony*
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/programme)

An *engaging content program* is parsed as a program that has *engaging content*. That is, a series of posts that are likely to be well-received. The email marketer is asserting that their product will allow such programs to be quickly made available to a large (or more accurately, a rapidly expanding) audience.